# Определить позицию элемента по отношению к окну браузера

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью jQuery определить позицию элемента на странице?

Задача следующая: есть div-родитель, и у элемента родителя должен добавляться класс, если родитель находиться близко к правому краю окна браузера.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) - например

```js
var element = $("#mydiv");
var offset = element.offset();
element.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```